# Remove margin between axis and matrix plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In the following MWE, how can I remove the margin (red arrow) between the matrix and the axis?

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis equal,
    scale only axis,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
    every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0pt,yshift=-7pt, black, font=\scriptsize},
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty
    ]

    \addplot[
    matrix plot*,
    point meta=explicit]
    table[meta=C]{
        x y C
0 0 0.0
0 1 0.0
0 2 0.3

1 0 0.0
1 1 1.0
1 2 0.0

2 0 0.0
2 1 0.0
2 2 .7
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to adjust the bounding box with Ti*k*Z methods. Not sure if that's what you're after, though.

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \begin{axis}[%
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis equal,
    scale only axis,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
    every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0pt,yshift=-7pt, black, font=\scriptsize},
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty
    ]

    \addplot[
    matrix plot*,
    point meta=explicit]
    table[meta=C]{
        x y C
0 0 0.0
0 1 0.0
0 2 0.3

1 0 0.0
1 1 1.0
1 2 0.0

2 0 0.0
2 1 0.0
2 2 .7
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \draw[use as bounding box] ([xshift=1cm,yshift=0.5cm]current axis.south west) 
    rectangle ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current axis.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is equivalent to the what is written in the pgfplots manual on p. 379.

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis equal,
    scale only axis,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
    every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0pt,yshift=-7pt, black, font=\scriptsize},
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty
    ]

    \addplot[
    matrix plot*,
    point meta=explicit]
    table[meta=C]{
        x y C
0 0 0.0
0 1 0.0
0 2 0.3

1 0 0.0
1 1 1.0
1 2 0.0

2 0 0.0
2 1 0.0
2 2 .7
    };
    \end{axis}
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \draw[use as bounding box] ([xshift=1cm,yshift=0.5cm]current axis.south west) 
    rectangle ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current axis.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```